# Create a plane of points from a row of points

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to create a "plane", so to speak, of points in MATLAB from a set of initial points. I have so far been able to create only one row of points, with the algorithm shown below:

```
    % Generate molecular orientation and position
a = 4.309; % lattice constant in angstroms
l = 10; % number of lattices desired

placeHolder = [0 0 0 ; a/2 a/2 0; a/2 0 a/2; 0 a/2 a/2];    % centers of molecules

numMol = 4; %input('how many molecules are in the unit cell? \n # molecules = ');
numAtoms = 2; %input('how many atoms per molecule? \n # atoms per molecule = ');
atomPerUC = numMol*numAtoms; % number of atoms per unit cell
dir = zeros(numMol,3);      % array for orientations
atomPosition = zeros(numAtoms*l^3,3,numMol);        % array for positions of atoms
theta = zeros(numMol,1);        % array for theta values
phi = zeros(numMol,1);      % array for phi values
b = 1.54;      % bond length in angstroms

for kk = 1:numMol % generate unit cell
%     disp(['What is the molecular orientation for molecule ',num2str(kk),' ?']);
%     dir(kk,1) = input('u = '); % ask for user input for molecular orientations
%     dir(kk,2) = input('v = ');
%     dir(kk,3) = input('w = ');
    dir = [1,1,1;-1,1,1;-1,-1,1;1,-1,1];
    u = dir(kk,1);       % set variables for theta, phi computation
    v = dir(kk,2);
    w = dir(kk,3);

    theta(kk) = w/sqrt(u^2+v^2+w^2); % theta value for molecule k

    if v<0   % phi value for molecule k
        phi(kk) = 2*pi - acos(abs(v)/sqrt(u^2+v^2+w^2));
    else if v>0
           phi(kk) = acos(u/sqrt(u^2+v^2+w^2)); 
        end
    end

    theta = theta(kk); phi = phi(kk);     % set variables for theta, phi for x,y,z computation

    xp = placeHolder(kk,1);      % cooridnates of center of molecule k
    yp = placeHolder(kk,2);
    zp = placeHolder(kk,3);

    x1 = (b/2)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) + xp;        % cooridnates for atoms in molecule
    x2 = -(b/2)*sin(theta)*cos(phi) + xp;
    y1 = (b/2)*sin(theta)*sin(phi) + yp;
    y2 = -(b/2)*sin(theta)*sin(phi) + yp;
    z1 = (b/2)*cos(theta) + zp;
    z2 = -(b/2)*cos(theta) + zp;

    atomPosition(1,:,kk) = [x1 y1 z1];
    atomPosition(2,:,kk) = [x2 y2 z2];
end

for k = 1:numMol

    x01 = atomPosition(1,1,k); y01 = atomPosition(1,2,k); z01 = atomPosition(1,3,k);
    x02 = atomPosition(2,1,k); y02 = atomPosition(2,2,k); z02 = atomPosition(2,3,k);

    for ii = 1:l-1
        atomPosition(2*ii+1,:,k) = [(atomPosition(2*ii-1,1,k) + a) y01 z01];
        atomPosition(2*ii+2,:,k) = [(atomPosition(2*ii,1,k) + a) y02 z02];
    end

end
```

My problem is that I do not know how to, from here, turn this "row" of points into a "plane" of points. This can be thought of as taking the points that are known on the x-axis, and creating similar rows moving up in the y-direction to create an x-y plane of points.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: This is a lot of code for just trying to reshape a vector into an array. Please post a [mcve] including which "row" you're trying to convert and what the dimensions of the resulting plane are.

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not understand exactly what you are trying to do. In a simple case you can move from a row of points to a plane by adding the extra dimension.

ie.

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=x^2
```

changes to

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y)
z=x^2+y^2
```